# Use the result of a Select statement result for another query in mssql server 2008

Tags: sql-server

I have a table forms from which I query out a set of result using

SELECT form_id from forms where customer_id = 200.

I get a set of results like

14
67
90
177
289
800

Now I have separate table based on these form id's like form_{form_id}*details. I want to look into each of the table based on the form id's obtained and count the number of records. If form*{form_id}_details has any record (i.e count(*) as cnt > 0), I want to get the count. I'm using PHP along with mssql server. Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: @shree.pat18: Can you please explain it with my problem? I'm not very strong in databases.

Comment: Please try to search for keywords Dynamic SQL so that you can read up on the concept from MSDN and other great sources. In a nutshell it lets you build a query string as per your requirement as a text string and then execute it to get desired results.

Comment: Thank you. Will try it out now.  @shree.pat18 :)